# Responsive elements not reflowing properly?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout

I am struggling with getting the elements on this page to reflow correctly: http://www.cmattayers.com/moushegianlaw/

I want the semi-transparent box to be flush with the left side of the slider image (the photo of the gavel), and for them to be "fused together." The problem now is that when the window becomes narrower, the semi-transparent callout box drops below the portrait photo, but the slider photo stays where it is. I have tried different combinations of inline and block elements to achieve the desired effect, but nothing seems to change.

I also have a bizarre sliver of space to the left side of the semi-transparent box that I can't seem to get rid of. Adding negative left margins does fix it, but when it drops below, it's off-center and outside of view.

I also need to find a way to add padding to the bottom of the box. When the window is resized to show mobile view, the bottom of the box rests directly on the header text below (I would like there to be padding, but adding padding seems to add it to the text inside the box and not the outside of the box).

Comment: Can you please share this in jsfiddle so that we can check with that?

Answer (score 0):

In that design, you've done a couple of HTML and CSS things I'd recommend against.

1. Firstly, your `<div id="header">` should be a `<header>` element. That's more semantic and accessible. If you use multiple headers on the page (which is allowed), you can distinguish this one using `role='banner'`.
2. You shouldn't put all those blocks into the header. Rather keep the logo in the `header`, put the menu in a `<nav>`, and put the portrait + gavel image + dark paragraph into a `<section>`.
3. Next, and to answer your question, perhaps don't use `inline` and `float` to position the paragraph. `inline` and `inline-block` are great for flowing content, but not great for content you want to always be in one row. Rather give the parts `display: table-cell` (or use the new 'flexbox' CSS styles).

To get this right, you may need to restructure your HTML a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the changes to the HTML that you suggested the best that I could. Could you elaborate a bit on your third point? I tried using display: table-cell on the various items in different combinations and it didn't seem to do anything. I think I must be misunderstanding what you were thinking.

Comment: Basically consecutive html elements (eg. if they're directly inside the same div) that have the css `display: table-cell` will always be displayed next to each other (i.e. horizontally on the same line). Also, it's often useful to also give those 'table-cells' `vertical-align: top` (you'll see what happens if you do / don't).